# Symfony Search Between Date on same day

Tags: php, symfony, date

I have a query builder who search in my db, between 2 dates.
I can not specify that the search must be from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.
Do you know or I have to put it please? All my attempts resulted in an error.

Here is my controller :

```
 public function searchAction(Request $request){
```

// TODO MAXLIMIT

```
    $defaultData = [];
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('from', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'datepicker'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('to', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'datepicker2'
            ]])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BudgetBundle:Debit');



        $from = $form['from']->getData();
        var_dump($from);
        $to = $form['to']->getData();
        $debits = $em->getByDate($from, $to);
        return $this->render('@Budget/Views/search.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView(), 'debits' => $debits]);


    }
```

My repo :

```
    public function getByDate($from, $to){



    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("d");
    $qb
        ->where('d.date BETWEEN :from AND :to')
        ->setParameter('from', $from->format('d-MM-yy' . '00:00:00') )
        ->setParameter('to', $to);
  return  $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

The js views :

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#form_from" ).datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        altField: "#datepicker",
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
        weekHeader: 'Sem.',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
    $( "#form_to" ).datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        altField: "#datepicker",
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
        weekHeader: 'Sem.',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});  } );
```

Comment: First of all for DateTime manipulation I'd recommend to use `Carbon` http://carbon.nesbot.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repo, format the date first, then append the appropriate hours. Make sure there's a space between the date and time:

```
$qb
    ->where('d.date BETWEEN :from AND :to')
    ->setParameter('from', $from->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')
    ->setParameter('to', $to->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59');
```

Comment: GREAT !
The answer was the SPACE ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mis-match in your function for the query parameters.
Try;

```
public function getByDate($from, $to){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("d");
    $qb
        ->where('d.date BETWEEN :from AND :to')
        ->setParameter(':from', $from->format('d-MM-yy' . '00:00:00') )
        ->setParameter(':to', $to);
  return  $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Also, just check your date format is coorect. Most databases store the date in format YYYY-mm-dd, so the correct format would be `->setParameter(':from', $from->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')`
Also, if you want the whole day, why not adjust your to date to be the next day and do where greater or equal to from, less then to.
E.g.

```
public function getByDate(\DateTime $from, \DateTime $to) {
    $end = clone $from;
    $end->modify('+1 day');
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("d");
    $qb
        ->where('d.date >= :from AND d.date < :end')
        ->setParameter(':from', $from->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00') )
        ->setParameter(':end', $end->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    return  $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping ;)
I need to have results for 1 day and for multiples days :)
It work's now !

Answer (score 0):

First of all for DateTime manipulation I'd recommend to use `Carbon` http://carbon.nesbot.com/.

To answer your question:

If you query does not depend on time, then comparing 2 dates are fine. If you comparison depend on time as well, then you need `DateTime`.